# How can I repeat XML code while keeping it DRY?

Tags: xml, refactoring, dry, code-duplication

I want to keep my code DRY for efficiency and maintenance. I write A LOT of XML for my programs and I was wondering how I can repeat code in the same file or from different files and directories without repeating my code.

```
<my-widget title="my title" value="my value"/>

<my-second-widget title="my second title" value="my second value"/>


<!-- big blocks of code -->


...


<!-- end of block of code -->



<my-widget title="my title" value="my value"/>

<my-second-widget title="my second title" value="my second value"/>
```

Comment: XML is simply a data representation format. The answer to your question depends on what is *interpreting* the data.

Comment: that doesnt help at all. Some python code is interpreting it

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions:

(a) use XML external entities (the same entity can be referenced from more than one place)

(b) use XInclude (ditto)

(c) redesign the XML to better reflect the structure of your data. For example if two widgets can have the same widget-body, then allow a `<widget>` element to contain a reference to a `<widget-body>` element:

```
<widget id="w1" ref="body1"/>
<widget id="w2" ref="body1"/>
<widget-body id="body1">....</widget-body>
```